# btrfs show command doesn't work when using snapshots

Tags: btrfs

Can someone explain why mounting a snapshot (essentially a subvolume I guess) after having set it as the "Default" results in the show command no longer working as well as the dir contents of the snapshots disappearing.  It seems kinda pointless to have a snapshot system that only works so long as you DONT use it.  Once it's explained why it works this way, explain how to get it to work the way I want which is described below.

Scenerio:  I have a root btrfs setup with / and NO subvolumes for /home, /root,  etc as I dislike such setups and want to avoid doing it at all costs.  It simply isn't what I want because then I couldn't revert the entire system with just 1 snapshot (similar to virtualbox snapshot reverts).  I don't care about losing user content or system config via a snapshot revert.  I want it to revert EVERYTHING to a specific point in time while not losing the ability to browse pre-existing snapshot contents of other dates (both past and if possible, future relative to the current snapshot).  The only "subvolumes" I have are snapshots.

This shows my current mount setup with btrfs being the last one in the list.  I truncated it since all the others are irrelevent.

```
root@Work-VirtualBox ~ # mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8179248k,nr_inodes=2044812,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1642476k,mode=755)
/dev/sda1 on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,compress=lzo,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=634,subvol=/snapshots/09-25-2022-03:00:01)
... yada yada
```

Current subvol list (all snapshots)

```
sudo btrfs subvol list /
ID 625 gen 1695 top level 5 path snapshots/test5
ID 626 gen 1694 top level 5 path snapshots/09-25-2022-01:40:33
ID 627 gen 1694 top level 5 path snapshots/09-25-2022-01:42:21
ID 628 gen 1694 top level 5 path snapshots/09-25-2022-01:42:28
ID 629 gen 1695 top level 5 path snapshots/09-25-2022-01:48:47
ID 630 gen 2782 top level 5 path snapshots/09-25-2022-01:50:42
ID 631 gen 1695 top level 5 path snapshots/09-25-2022-01:51:28
ID 632 gen 1695 top level 5 path snapshots/09-25-2022-01:52:25
ID 633 gen 2720 top level 5 path snapshots/09-25-2022-01:58:45
ID 634 gen 2691 top level 5 path snapshots/09-25-2022-03:00:01
ID 635 gen 2654 top level 634 path snapshots/09-25-2022-03:00:01/snapshots/test6
```

Current default snapshot:

```
sudo btrfs subvol get-default /
ID 630 gen 2783 top level 5 path snapshots/09-25-2022-01:50:42
```

Problem:

Whenever I set the "default" snapshot to anything other than ID 5,  I lose the ability to use btrfs subvol show as well as `ls -latch /snapshots/NAMEHERE`.  If I set the default to 5,  then show works for ALL the snapshots and I am able to browse the /snapshots dir as one would expect.  It doesn't matter what ID I use.  I tried 625, 630, and 634.   While I was using 634,  I created a NEW snapshot called test6.  When I am using 634 as default, the ONLY snapshot that I can use the show command on is test6 (which is id 635).  I'm also able to browse its contents in the /snapshots dir.

Expected results:

I was expecting to be able to switch to any snapshot and still be able to browse other snapshots OLDER than the one I switched to.  That simply isn't the case here.  I can see that the dir listing of /snapshots only shows older snapshots, but the contents of those directories are completely EMPTY and show no files at all.  I was expecting them to show files,  not just the snapshot name.  I would also expect the "btrfs subvol show" command to show details of at least the OLDER ones, and it would be nice if it also worked for the NEWER ones as well.

I also find it rather strange that the parent (ID: 5) isn't listed anywhere.  It should show up in the list with children of all the snapshots I created.  I don't even know how it got ID: 5 since it's literally the first time it was used;  I'd expect it to be ID: 1,  not ID: 5.

```
sudo btrfs subvol show -r 5 /snapshots/test5
ERROR: cannot resolve rootid for path: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ERROR: can't find rootid '5' on '/snapshots/test5': -25
ERROR: Failed to get subvol info /snapshots/test5: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

```
sudo btrfs subvol show /snapshots/test5
ERROR: not a subvolume: /snapshots/test5
ERROR: Failed to get subvol info /snapshots/test5: 1
```

Current work-around:

The only workaround to get the btrfs show command working as well as dir contents being listed in the snapshots is to set the default subvol back to ID: 5.  However,  that just sounds all wrong to me.  I should be able to set it to any snapshot I want and whatever I do from then on simply makes the current snapshot a parent of whatever I do from that point forward until I set the default snapshot to another ID.  If I don't make a new snapshot before setting to a new ID,  I'd expect to LOSE anything I did which is exactly the behavior I want.  If I want to save work,  I'd need to make a new snapshot which becomes a child of the snapshot I was working in.